# Should i sanitize user inputs in express js?

Tags: node.js, express, html-encode, html-escape-characters, express-validator

I used express-validator escape() to sanitize user inputs and saved escaped data in database using parameterized query. When i render the input from database using EJS view engine i get escaped characters. For example ' becomes `&#x27;`
Do i need to unescape them while rendering? or I shouldn't use sanitize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to always store the raw data, so if the user sends "<h1>", you store "<h1>" on your database, then you [escape the string on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5499821/12397250) (or on server side if you are using server side rendering) before showing it on the HTML to [prevent XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2334863/12397250). So dont `escape()` the string on your express app, just store the raw text.