# How do I search through all .jsp files for certain tags and attributes?

Tags: xml, jsp, search, jsf

We discovered an XSS issues on our site.  My job is to now go through all the source code finding where it might else be occurring.

I am limiting my search to a specific JSF issue.  But the solution should work regardless of what I want to search.

Essentially I want a list of JSF files.  I need to get list that has this criteria: search all *.jsp files that have the `<h:outputText` tag and with in that tag, have the "escape" attribute and the "value" attribute containing "{"

I don't have access to a static source code analyzer at work yet.

**Any ideas on how I could do such a search?**

Most of my searches like this involve Regular Expression Searches with TextPad.  But I am hoping there might be some better ideas out there on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search on `escape="false"` in `*.jsp`. That should be sufficient. To fix XSS holes, you should then ensure that it does not output user-controlled input and then remove the `escape="false"` attribute. If this user-controlled input is intented to be redisplayed literally as HTML, then you'd like to sanitize it from mailcious tags first. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206850/how-to-prevent-javascript-injection-xss-when-jstl-escapexml-is-false/4207292#4207292).

Comment: I agree with all your points about XSS. I need to make the XSS change you suggest.  The problem is that escape="false" is not enough because we use it all over the place to put static text on the screen such as adding "<p>" or "<b>". I am trying to limit what to research.

Comment: So, it's a vintage JSF 1.0/1.1 webapplication? Since JSF 1.2, which was already released over 5 years ago, you could just put static HTML among JSF tags without the need to fiddle with `h:outputText` or `f:verbatim`.

Comment: Sorry to say we are using vintage JSF 1.1.