# request.getParameter protect against XSS : what is the best practice?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, xss

I've inherited a large code base of 1000+ JSP-files that is full of XSS-vulnerabilities.

The code is full of

```
<%= request.getParameter("theparam")%>
```

and

```
out.println("some stuff before"+request.getParameter("theparam")+"and some other stuff");
```

and

```
String myVar = request.getParameter("theparam");
out.println(myVar);
```

I want to secure all files without having to go through all of them individually.

What is my best approach ?

- Do a 'replace all' on "request.getParameter("xx")" to "StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(request.getParameter("xx")) on all source files ?
- Can i somehow override the function 'request.getParameter' so it defaults to stringescapeutils.escapehtml(request.getParameter("")); ?

thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not saying this is the best approach, but:

> Can i somehow override the function 'request.getParameter' so it defaults to stringescapeutils.escapehtml(request.getParameter("")); ?

is easily achievable using servlet filter and by wrapping HTTP servlet request. This approach is described in [How to add validation logic to HttpServletRequest](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_add_validation_logic_to_HttpServletRequest).

However the most comprehensive approach is to escape when displaying, preferably only in JSP. Too bad you also generate HTML in servlets. See: [Java 5 HTML escaping To Prevent XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333586).

Comment: Anyone a regexp gury ?

I want to replace all occurrences of 
    request.getParameter("thischangesallthetime")
to
    stringescapeutils.escapehtml(request.getParameter(""));

Can i do it with a regular expression replace ?

Comment: @user1194465: absolutely you can, but please post another question (maybe it's even more suited on superuser?) and follow-up here. Also I am not sure whether this is a good approach - you should escape parameters when showing, not when reading.

Comment: ok, i've done this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500695/notepad-regulare-expression-to-replace]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils" %>
String str=request.getParameter("urlParam");
String safeOuput = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(str);
```

Hope this will help you to resolve the problem...