# Notepad++ : regulare expression to replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a bunch of files where i want to replace

```
request.getParameter("thischangesallthetime")
```

to

```
stringescapeutils.escapehtml(request.getParameter("thischangesallthetime"));
```

Can i do this in Notepad++ ? 
And what regular expression can i use ?

thnx!

Answer (score 0):

Search:

```
request.getParameter\("(.*?)"\)
```

Replace

```
stringescapeutils.escapehtml\(request.getParameter\("\1"\)\);
```

EDIT: as duncan correctly points out, the matching on the search regex needs to be non-greedy if you have more than one replaceable expression on one line. I corrected the search regex to take this into account.

PS: next time please show us what you tried.

Comment: The .* will be greedy, you probably want to use (.*?) instead, in case there is more than one ) in the text

Comment: I don't see any problem for .* being greedy in this case.

Answer (score 0):

m0skit0's answer is a starter, but it needs modification if you should have more than one of these values in your string.  Example:

> hello request.getParameter("thischangesallthetime")  lorem ipsum
>   request.getParameter("foobar")  blah

needs this regex:

Find:

```
request.getParameter\("(.*?)"\)
```

Replace with:

```
stringescapeutils.escapehtml(request.getParameter("\1"));
```

The ? in the regex makes it non-greedy.  Otherwise the first match (at 'thisvaluechangesallthetime') will just grab everything up the very last ") in the second match (at 'foobar')

And you shouldn't need to escape the parentheses in the replace part of the regex.

Without the ?, you end up with this as the result:

```
hello stringescapeutils.escapehtml(request.getParameter("thischangesallthetime") lorem ipsum request.getParameter("foobar")); blah
```

Notice the escapehtml parentheses don't end until after the ("foobar") parameter!

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape the parentheses in your replacement - when I do this, it inserts \ into the string all over the place

Comment: For me it does not insert the parenthesis with your replace regex... What NP++ version are you in? Regexes changed quite a bit around version 6 to make them PCRE. I'm on 6.1.3.

Comment: ah, I'm only on 5.9.6.2, that explains it